Disabling and re-enabling SELinux permanently disables policy
I have installed a monitoring system based on Nagios on a RHEL 9.4 machine in order to check the status of a systemd unit.
The check wasn´t working and after some troubleshooting we realized that SeLinux was getting in the way and after setting it into disabled mode we got it working.
But then after re-setting SELinux into enforcing mode the check kept on working, which is jarring to say the least as we expected for it to be blocked again.
After this I setup a separate test machine in order to investigate this anomaly and it turned out to be repeatable, even by reverting to a snapshot previous to setting of SELinux in disabled mode.

I revert the machine to a previous snapshot
Nagios's dashboard is unable to check the unit status
I check with sealert -l "*" that SELinux is blocking the check
I set SELinux in disabled mode
After rebooting the system the check starts to work
I re-set SELinux in enforcing mode
The check still works and sealert -l "*" prints no new errors.

I wanted to ask you whether this behaviour is to be expected or whether we have stumbled upon a bug that needs to be fixed by the SELinux developers.

You haven't provided enough information here for us to answer the question. What are the specific AVC messages logged when the check fails? Perhaps it's performing a one-time operation that, having succeeded once, it doesn't need to repeat.
